polycom failed to upload cfg file for polycom phone from vsftpd /home/vvx310 directory
The other day I was trying to get my polycom up and running but could not understand why I can log into the phone's built in web server.
So the question is why?
Here is the phone settings:
provision server: DHCP is status everything left default:
Server type FTP 
server address: 192.168.12.2
server user: vvx310
server password: xxxxxx
rest of commands are default 
LTS security: disabled
GMT: untouched default 0
DNS: set to the Google DNS servers 
DNS domain: untouched factory default : blank
Hostname: blank 

There are no other settings. No option to turn on the built in web server.
Lastly I need also a copy of all the cfg files for phone. I am using what I thought was cfg files for this phone but read the readme.txt and this phone is not included in the list.
When I am on the command line, type in “ftp > open > server ip > login” is does show the cfg files for the other makes so vsftpd is working and logging me in.
This is from /var/log/vsftpd.log file:
Wed Nov 20 14:31:25 2024 [pid 6868] [vvx310] OK LOGIN: Client "192.168.12.5"
Wed Nov 20 14:31:25 2024 [pid 6870] [vvx310] FAIL UPLOAD: Client "192.168.12.5", "/0004f2821bc4-boot.log", 0.00Kbyte/sec

I do not know where the mac macaddress-reg.log file is located.
Here is the vsftp.conf file. It should be working fine I cant log into the directory with the phone login/password info.
Example config file /etc/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
#
# Run standalone?  vsftpd can run either from an inetd or as a standalone
# daemon started from an initscript.
listen=yes

# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. By default, listening
# on the IPv6 "any" address (::) will accept connections from both IPv6
# and IPv4 clients. It is not necessary to listen on *both* IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets. If you want that (perhaps because you want to listen on specific
# addresses) then you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration
# files.
#listen_ipv6=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Disabled by default).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
#local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# If enabled, vsftpd will display directory listings with the time
# in  your  local  time  zone.  The default is to display GMT. The
# times returned by the MDTM FTP command are also affected by this
# option.
use_localtime=YES
#
# Activate logging of uploads/downloads.
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# You may override where the log file goes if you like. The default is shown
# below.
#xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
#
# If you want, you can have your log file in standard ftpd xferlog format.
# Note that the default log file location is /var/log/xferlog in this case.
#xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
#ascii_upload_enable=YES
#ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd.banned_emails
#
# You may restrict local users to their home directories.  See the FAQ for
# the possible risks in this before using chroot_local_user or
# chroot_list_enable below.
#chroot_local_user=YES
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
# (Warning! chroot'ing can be very dangerous. If using chroot, make sure that
# the user does not have write access to the top level directory within the
# chroot)
chroot_local_user=YES
#chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
#ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# Customization
#
# Some of vsftpd's settings don't fit the filesystem layout by
# default.
#
# This option should be the name of a directory which is empty.  Also, the
# directory should not be writable by the ftp user. This directory is used
# as a secure chroot() jail at times vsftpd does not require filesystem
# access.
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
#
# This string is the name of the PAM service vsftpd will use.
pam_service_name=vsftpd
#
# This option specifies the location of the RSA certificate to use for SSL
# encrypted connections.
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
ssl_enable=NO

#
# Uncomment this to indicate that vsftpd use a utf8 filesystem.
#utf8_filesystem=YES

I changed the 000000000000.cfg to the correctmacaddress.cfg of the phone. This file wont work as shown in the readme.txt:
cat  /home/vvx310/0004f2821bc4.cfg
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Default Master SIP Configuration File-->
<!-- For information on configuring Polycom VoIP phones please refer to the -->
<!-- Configuration File Management white paper available from: -->
<!-- http://www.polycom.com/common/documents/whitepapers/configuration_file_management_on_soundpoint_ip_phones.pdf -->
<!-- $RCSfile$  $Revision: 155255 $ -->
<APPLICATION APP_FILE_PATH="sip.ld" CONFIG_FILES="" MISC_FILES="" LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY="/home/vvx310/log" OVERRIDES_DIRECTORY="" CONTACTS_DIRECTORY="" LICENSE_DIRECTORY="" USER_PROFILES_DIRECTORY="" CALL_LISTS_DIRECTORY="">
   
<!-- not used for troubleshooting --!>
<!-- <APPLICATION_SPIP300 APP_FILE_PATH_SPIP300="sip_213.ld" CONFIG_FILES_SPIP300="phone1_213.cfg, sip_213.cfg"/> 
   <APPLICATION_SPIP500 APP_FILE_PATH_SPIP500="sip_213.ld" CONFIG_FILES_SPIP500="phone1_213.cfg, sip_213.cfg"/>
</APPLICATION> -->

